# Can linear search be executed in a O(log n) time by incrementing the loop variable by 2 instead of 1?

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity, linear-search

The crucial change in the code could be something like:

```
// while loop from 0 to n - 2; i initially = 0
if( arr[i + 1] != element && arr[i] != element) i += 2; 
else if(arr[i] == element){ cout << "Element present at: " << i; }  
else{ cout << "Element is present at: " << i + 1; return 0; }
```

What do you think?

Comment: `O(n/2)` remains on the order of `O(n)`

Comment: No. log(n) is when one **divides in half** (or any other const ratio <=1/2) **current** size of a problem for **each new subdivision**, i.e. your problem size was `16`, and then became `8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1`. If one divides **in half** a problem **only once** it's O(n/2) ~= O(n). What you did doesn't make sense at all. If you execute your loop 2 times less but do 2 times more work inside of it you don't gain anything

Comment: Also, if your `n` is odd you have to check the last element as well after the loop, which makes your code more complicated and less readable then it should be

Comment: what you want is binary search but that only works on sorted data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. In the worst case you have to look at every element and there are `n` of them.